# Prestigio PAP 7500 rooting

Tags: rooting, rom

recently I bought **Prestigio 7500** for testing reasons and what is stopping me from doing it is that I can't root it (I want to install custom rom such as CM or Ubuntu touch). I was searching **CWM** (ClockworkMod) - there is none , other alternative mods and I found also nothing. I was also searching for any forums related to this device ,I found some in Czech and Slovak (had to use translator) but how I understood they didnt succeed also and this situation really frustrates me because I found almost nothing about this device.. Maybe some of you were sucessfull rooting this device or know where to find any explantion or how-to or any forum ? Any suggestions is really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [Towelroot](https://towelroot.com/)? Should support all phones < jun 3 2014.

Comment: Will try this  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rooting is the easiest part, but it still may be impossible. Some of the methods I would try:

- You can try to log in through ADB, see if you're already logged in as root.
- You can also try universal root exploits, one of them may work.
- Also you can try to obtain an original ROM for the device, root it on the PC and flash it on the device.

What **is *very*** hard (handfuls of experienced developers are spending months with each device) is porting custom ROMs (CM, Ubuntu Touch) to a previously unsupported device. Since you've found no existing recovery for it, let alone a ROM, you will have to do the porting yourself which will take a lot of time and if you aren't careful, you can easily brick your device.

Comment: I will try this method with ADB. By the way the question is for those who maybe had the same issue and could share it with me :/

Answer (score 1):

Rooting this device is very easy. Just search for Framaroot app on jellydroid.com, install it on phone and run, choose install Super SU and Barahir exploit, reboot phone and your done. Tested and working.

Comment: Here is the link, that you did not mention http://www.jellydroid.com/2014/10/how-to-root-prestigio-multiphone-7500-smartphone/ and the Framaroot Apk http://www.jellydroid.com/framaroot-1-9-0-apk/

Comment: @JustMe Thanks , I had successfully rooted my device with Framaroot. Do you know any working custom roms or recoverymods? I have managed to install cwm but I think its because of mine poor knowledge its full of bugs and very laggy .. Any suggestions ?